# QuickSort implementation not working for large input

Tags: quicksort

Can anyone tell me why my quickSortHelper function doesn't solve for large input?

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
  public static int[] quickSort(int[] array) {
        // Write your code here.
        quickSortHelper(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        return array;
    }

    public static void quickSortHelper(int[] array, int l, int r){
        if(l >= r){
            return;
        }
        int pivot = l;
        int leftIndex = l + 1;
        int rightIndex = r;
        while(rightIndex >= leftIndex ){
            if(array[leftIndex] > array[pivot] && array[rightIndex] < array[pivot]){
                swap(leftIndex, rightIndex, array);
            }
            if(array[leftIndex] <= array[pivot]){
                leftIndex += 1;
            }
            if(array[rightIndex] >= array[pivot]){
                rightIndex -= 1;
            }
        }
        swap(pivot, rightIndex, array);
        boolean leftSubarrayIsSmaller = rightIndex - 1 - l < r - (rightIndex + 1);
        if(leftSubarrayIsSmaller){
            quickSortHelper(array, rightIndex + 1, l);
            quickSortHelper(array, l, rightIndex - 1);
        }else{
            quickSortHelper(array, l, rightIndex - 1);
            quickSortHelper(array, rightIndex + 1, l);
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int i, int j, int[] array){
        int temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Here's my test case, I think if I solve for this it will be an efficient implementation.

```
int[] array7 = {-4, 5, 10, 8, -10, -6, -4, -2, -5, 3, 5, -4, -5, -1, 1, 6, -7, -6, -7, 8};
```

The current result is as follows

```
[-10, -7, -6, -7, -6, -5, -4, -5, -4, 3, 5, -4, -2, -1, 1, 6, 8, 10, 5, 8]
```

As you can see, still not completely sorted. This does work for smaller input, as in less than 10 numbers.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two lines that look like this, and they do nothing:

`quickSortHelper(array, rightIndex + 1, l);`

Replace the `l` with an `r`:

`quickSortHelper(array, rightIndex + 1, r);`

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't catch that!